# "* Missing C library: GL" when installing gloss (specifically the OpenGLRaw dependency) on Ubuntu

Tags: opengl, haskell, gloss, openglraw

I get the following error when trying to install gloss:

```
Configuring OpenGLRaw-1.5.0.1...
Failed to install OpenGLRaw-1.5.0.1
Build log ( /home/<homdir>/.cabal/logs/OpenGLRaw-1.5.0.1.log ):
Configuring OpenGLRaw-1.5.0.1...
setup-Simple-Cabal-1.18.1.5-x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.4: Missing dependency on a
foreign library:
* Missing C library: GL
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
```

Normally I would try installing `libgl-dev` based on the usual naming convention, but there is no such library.

Answer (score 18):

With most missing C libraries it's obvious what to install; no so for openGL. For me, installing following packages got things moving again.

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev
```